# Convert Spark DataFrame to spark.rdd.RDD[(Array[Integer], Array[Integer]) to calculate mean average precision

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, multidimensional-array, rdd, average-precision

I have a Spark DataFrame:

[image: DataFrame]

I have to use Spark with Scala to calculate mean average precision from [RankingMetrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#ranking-systems).
I guess according to the documentation we have to use RDD instead of DataFrame.
I tried the following:

```
var llist = df.select("predicted", "actual").rdd.map(x => (x.get(0), x.get(1))).collect()
// It gave Array[(Any, Any)]

var df_rdd =sc.parallelize(llist)
// df_rdd is org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Any, Any)]

val metrics = new RankingMetrics(df_rdd)
// This gave me an error
```

**Error** :

> error: type mismatch;
> found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Any, Any)]
> required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Array[?], Array[?])]
> Note: (Any, Any) >: (Array[?], Array[?]), but class RDD is invariant in type T.
> You may wish to define T as -T instead. (SLS 4.5)

I am using Spark version 2.4.3

How can I convert this DataFrame to that format so I can calculate mean average precision? Thanks.

Comment: what is your dataframe schema? Can you pose the example data to test your process? The image is not possible to copy and recreate the problem.

Comment: @Lamanus Both the columns are an array(or a list)
You can create sample using this:
val df = Seq(
  (List(1, 9,16), List(27, 729, 688)),
  (List(1, 4, 548), List()),
  (List(1,5,3), List(688))
).toDF("predicted", "actual")

Answer (score 0):

A `DataFrame` is essentially an `RDD` under the covers and your `DataFrame` has the type `DataFrame[Array[Int], Array[Int]]`. So based on your types you are reporting, you should be able pass that directly to the `new RankingMetrics(df.rdd())`. Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

As the error simply tells that your params to RankingMetrics should be of type

> (Array[?], Array[?])

But when you will check your RDD which you can by simply typing **df.rdd**, it shows this:

> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]

So basically you have to convert this Row type of data to Array type. One way to do this is mapping it like this:

```
df.rdd.map(r=>(Array(r(0)),Array(r(1))))
```

This is not a suggested way. Also in your use case, don't start with creating a dataframe instead create an RDD with data of required type (in your case (Array[], Array[])). Also, to create an RDD from a dataframe you should use:

```
df.rdd
```